# ACF odd even repeater

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I have the following code where I will show differing div order depending on whether the repeater field is odd or even, but it is incorrect as it is repeating the even twice. Any help on the problem would be much appreciated.

```
 <!-- If Even -->
<?php if(get_field('services_repeater')): $i = 0; 
while(has_sub_field('services_repeater')): $i++;
if($i % 2 == 0 ):?>

<div class="row">
<div class="span6 area-text">
<?php the_sub_field('area_text'); ?>
</div>
<div class="span6">
<!-- Carousel Open -->
    <div class="slider lazy">
    <?php
    $variable = get_sub_field('choose_slider');
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'portfolio-item' =>  $variable->slug
    );              
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div><a class="group1"  href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><div class="image">
    <?php $imageID = get_field('thumbnail');
    $attachment_id = get_field('thumbnail');
        $size = "carousel_main_img";
        $imageURL = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size ); ?>
 <img data-lazy="<?php echo $imageURL[0]; ?>" />
 <div class="post-content"><p class="caption"><?php printf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?></p></div>
 </div></a></div>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div></div>
<!-- Carousel Closed -->
</div>
</div>
<div id="separator"></div>

<!-- End If Even -->
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="row">
<div class="span6 area-text">
<?php the_sub_field('area_text'); ?>
</div>
<div class="span6">
<!-- Carousel Open -->
    <div class="slider lazy">
    <?php
    $variable = get_sub_field('choose_slider');
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'portfolio-item' =>  $variable->slug
    );              
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div><a class="group1"  href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><div class="image">
    <?php $imageID = get_field('thumbnail');
    $attachment_id = get_field('thumbnail');
        $size = "carousel_main_img";
        $imageURL = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size ); ?>
 <img data-lazy="<?php echo $imageURL[0]; ?>" />
 <div class="post-content"><p class="caption"><?php printf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?></p></div>
 </div></a></div>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div></div>
<!-- Carousel Closed -->
</div>
</div>
<div id="separator"></div>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am afraid I don't have this online to show you, I have tried simplifying this to the following code, and still the second is repeating twice.

```
<?php if ( get_field( 'services_repeater' ) ): ?>
  <?php $index = 1; ?>
   <?php $totalNum = count( get_field('services_repeater') ); ?>
    <?php while ( has_sub_field( 'services_repeater' ) ): ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <?php the_sub_field('area_text'); ?>
    </div>
    <? if ($index % 2 == 0) : ?>
        <? if ($index < $totalNum) : ?>
          Row 2<?php the_sub_field('area_text'); ?>
        <? elseif ($index == $totalNum) : ?>
        <? endif; ?>
    <? endif; ?>
<?php $index++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hey, your thought on using the modulo operator to detect the odd/even numbers is totally right.

Can you show us some sample output where the problem happens because from what i can read the code looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have an `else` block. Your code looks in short like this:

```
if (($i % 2)==0) {
    // do even

}
// do odd.
```

In the case of even *do even* and *do odd* will happen. The odd part must go into an else block:

```
if (($i % 2)==0) {
    // do even

} else {
    // do odd

}
```

The missing else block in your code is this line:

```
<!-- End If Even -->
<?php endif; ?>
// do odd
```

Replace that with an

```
<?php else: ?>
    // do odd
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while( have_rows('custom_section') ): the_row();

if( get_row_index() % 2 == 0 ){
    
    // this is an even row
    
    // code to display the image on the left
    
} else{
    
    // this is an odd row
    
    // code to display the image on the right
    
}
```

endwhile;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).